# Service exited with abnormal code: 255 in PyInstaller file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made packaging Mac app by PyInstaller. And I could work it.
But, when my friend opened the app, the person received following error in system.log.

What's the problem?
I will appreciate your help with this situation.

```
Jun 25 13:09:54 MacBookPro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Jun 25 13:10:05 MacBookPro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x1000002a.thename[49671]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Jun 25 13:10:11 MacBookPro kcm[49677]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

Comment: I don't think it is a Pyinstaller problem nor it is a python exception, maybe the error is related to your code. It is better to add a minimal version of your code for better help.

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for your reply. Do you know what is the best debugging method?

Comment: You should add your code and full error traceback. Usually, Pyinstaller output should work but maybe you are missing to bundle some external dependencies.

Comment: @M.R. I'm using chromedriver and wxpython. So maybe they might not bundle well..

Comment: How can I check error? I tried to open by cmd but error didn't appear.